# Looking for Windows installer software

Tags: software-rec, windows-installer

I have a small software. I want to put in an installer software.
Do you have any suggestions (free/commercial)
Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/) is quite common. (But +1 for InnoSetup, too.)

Answer (score 7):

I use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for all my installers. It's free and fairly extensible. I also recommend [ISTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) as a better IDE for InnoSetup.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have much experience with it, but I've heard [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is good.

Comment: It's painful (if you're not used to XML design) but worth the pain. :-)

Comment: Worth noting that 1) WiX is an official tool by Microsoft, 2) it outputs MSI packages for Windows Installer, rather than standalone EXE installer programs.